# No access to files in root directory

Tags: apache, xampp, symfony

I am using Symfony 3 and XAMPP Version 7.0.9. I have created a virtual host which is called `diary`. In Symfony I think the root directory is `web`. Anyway in the directory `web` there is a file called `favicon.ico`. Now if I go to `diary/favicon.ico`, I get the error:

> No route found for "GET /favicon.ico"

This is how my configuration looks in `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/diary/web/app_dev.php"
    ServerName diary
</VirtualHost>
```

I have spent more than 4 hours on that issue and I couldn't figure out why this is happening. Please somebody tell me what's going on here.

Comment: You will need a bit more configuration: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#apache-with-mod-php-php-cgi In addition, add "Require local" under "Allow from All" for windows.  Might also want to lookup how to add additional server names to the windows hosts file.  But the easiest thing to do is to simply run bin/console server:run.  No apache needed. http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#running-the-symfony-application

Comment: @Cerad you my man deserve a beer! I didn't know about `server:run` but that makes things definitely much easier! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

In hosts add **diary.loc** C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 diary.loc
```

in httpd-vhosts.conf You mast add same Symfony values:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName diary.loc
  ServerAlias www.diary.loc 

  DocumentRoot  "C:/xampp/htdocs/diary/web"
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/diary/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You have reached it as http://diary.loc/app_dev.php or http://diary.loc